# Extended Num Keypad.

Tags: pt-quick-keys, macbook-pro, experiences

Hey.
I recently migrated to a mac book pro  after being a longtime windows user. I am using PT10. I bought myself a [Dynex Extended Keypad](http://www.dynexproducts.com/products/computer-accessories/DX-KEYPAD2.html), just for the ease of using PT. But I am not able to open the transport window, session settings etc .. (Command+ Num keypad Options)

Is it because MBP doesn't have the num lock setting or do I simply need to buy another keypad. Anyone ever encountered the same issue? I'm new to mac so don't know everything about it as yet. Kindly help. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just get the [Apple keyboard with Num pad](http://store.apple.com/us/product/MB110LL/B/apple-keyboard-with-numeric-keypad)?

I got one second hand for half the RRP. You're still only using up one USB port and there ports on the keyboard which I use to connect mouse and iLok.

Answer (score 1):

FWIW I use KeyRemap4MacBook to get some of the functionality of the numeric keyboard. I use the option "Change Num Key (1…0)" and then it becomes a matter of fn+1 fn+2 and so on to access that functionality.

Answer (score 0):

The dynex is only PC compatible

Comment: ^ Good reason...

Comment: But is there any other extended numeric keypad that is compatible with MBP?

Answer (score 0):

If you're used to work with a laptop I'll suggest you learn all the shortcuts again or try this :
1) http://dnamusiclabs.com/hotkey-matrix if you don't have the time to learn the shortcuts all over again
2) http://transom.org/wp/wp-content/uploads/2008/11/pro-tools-shortcuts.pdf?9d7bd4